# Can't generate Python docstring with autoDocstring extension in VS Code when multiline string in the function body

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, docstring

To generate documentation with Python Sphinx I have to use a specific docstring format.

VS Code extension **autoDocstring** is capable to generate this specific format, but if the function contains multiline string then it doesn't work.

Example in this case works:

```
def func(param1, param2, param3):
    # docstring nicely generated
    """_summary_

    :param param1: _description_
    :type param1: _type_
    :param param2: _description_
    :type param2: _type_
    :param param3: _description_
    :type param3: _type_
    :return: _description_
    :rtype: _type_
    """

    random_variable = 42
    string_variable = "not a multiline string"

    return string_variable
```

But in this case can't generate auto docstring:

```
def func(param1, param2, param3):
    # doesn't work
    """"""

    random_variable = 42
    string_variable = """
             a 
             multiline
             string
     """

    return string_variable
```

Anyone know a trick, or something to make it work?
I use a lot of multiline SQL strings in my functions and if I have to extract these strings just to make it work I need a lot of refactoring.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I figured out the solution and I post it here, maybe will help somebody.
Actually the solution is pretty straightforward.
I changed the triple apostrophes to triple single quotes in the function/class/whatever string variable and now autoDocstring's parser doesn't get confused.
Example:

```
def func(param1, param2, param3):
    # autoDocstring works
    """_summary_

    :param param1: _description_
    :type param1: _type_
    :param param2: _description_
    :type param2: _type_
    :param param3: _description_
    :type param3: _type_
    :return: _description_
    :rtype: _type_
    """

    random_variable = 42
    string_variable = '''
             a 
             multiline
             string
     '''

    return string_variable
```

Answer (score 7):

Keyboard shortcut: `ctrl+shift+2` or `cmd+shift+2` for mac